# make multi-line value from database into one line

Tags: php

Hello i am trying to get a value from a database which is multi-line . I echo the value normally by `echo $row['description'];` and the result is something like

```
the new part 3

he is working and prepared to enter the order. 

The witness sees me and talks example in preparation
```

now this is causing `Unexpected Token Illegal` if i try to get this value using javascript or jquery . How to make this multi-line value to be in single line as normal para or sentence .

Answer (score 0):

Try `str_replace("\n",' ',$row);`

That replaces the newline with a space. If that gives an extra space, then make it `str_replace("\n",'',$row);`

Comment: Please don't take this as impolite. If you're going to get much help at this site, you'll need to learn how to ask good questions. "it did not work" gives me no idea what went wrong so that maybe I can help you take the next step. Show some of your code in context. Show the actual output and the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You should  properly escape for a Javascript string:

```
echo str_replace(['\n', '\r', '\t', "'", '"', '\\'], ['\\n', '\\r', '\\t', "\\'", '\\"'], $row['description']);
```

There may be other characters you should escape, but I think I've covered the common ones that are likely to be in your strings.

Comment: i tried `$midesc = str_replace(['\n', '\r', '\t', "'", '"', '\\'], ['\\n', '\\r', '\\t', "\\'", '\\"'], $row['description']);` and then echo `$midesc` but nothing seems to be output

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code:

```
<?php
function js_escape($str)
{
    $str = str_replace("\\", "\\\\", strval($str));
    $str = str_replace("'", "\\'", $str);
    $str = str_replace("\r", "\\r", $str);
    $str = str_replace("\n", "\\n", $str);
    $str = str_replace("\t", "\\t", $str);
    $str = str_replace("</script>", "</'+'script>", $str);
    return $str;
}
?><script type="text/javascript">
var a = '<?php echo js_escape('text with special symbols'); ?>';
</script>
```

Comment: NOTE - single quotes in javascript around variable value